# Indexing Polish characters

Tags: indexing, xindy

I would like to generate an index with Polish glyphs (ś, ć for example) but LateX treats those fonts as symbols and they appear at the beginning of the index.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Hello \index{ć}\index{c}\index{ś}\index{s}\index{sa}\index{se}\index{a}\index{al}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indeks}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I run the command to create the index:

```
--language polish --debug level=3 --module lang/polish/latin2 −−log−file 'filename.ilg'  -I latex 'filename.idx'
```

I get the following:

[image]

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Have you tried `\index{<symbol>@<entry>}`, for example `\index{śymbol@symbol}`?

Answer (score 3):

If I try with

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[
  intoc,
  program=xindy,
  options=-C utf8 -L polish
]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Rozdział}

Hello \index{ć}\index{c}\index{ś}\index{s}\index{sa}\index{se}\index{a}\index{al}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

and compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`, the index will go in the table of contents automatically and will be typeset as follows

[image]

There is no need to run Xindy, as the `-shell-escape` option will run it automatically.

Comment: If it is possible to get the font ś within the group associated to the header Ś instead of the header S.

Comment: @markow Fixed, I believe

Comment: Still I don't get "ś" or "ć" in Index page - it appears only above "a" in "symbols".

markow@markow-Inspiron-5521:~$ xindy -V
xindy release: unknown
xindy script version: 1.08
xindy kernel version: 2.3
xindy run time engine: x86_64-linux, version 2.2
CLISP version 2.43 (2007-11-18) (built 3655233359) (memory 3655233433)
    architecture: X86_64

markow@markow-Inspiron-5521:~$ kile -v
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
Kile: 2.1.3


I compile in Kile using custom button with command:
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape '%source'

Another guess how to tshoot the problem?

Comment: @markow That's the output I get.