# Problem with indices in the Polish language

Tags: luatex, indexing, unicode, polish

Although I read some postings about indices on the forum, I still have trouble with making an index in Polish. I want to have bold letters before a group connected with a single letter (like in the first picture, which was taken from another post to demonstrate my goal, also with diacritic letters - Ć, Ś). The entries should be also sorted alphabetically (like Ć comes after C)

How can I achieve that?

Here is the code, which was compiled with `LuaLaTeX`, and `makeindex`: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rnfrvvbxhfgr

I added also the second picture, which shows the current result.

The code of index is divided into two files (only a short parts, because I'm not sure that it is all):

1. Preambuła/preambula.tex:

```
(...)

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polski}

(...)

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx} %obsługa indeksów 
\makeindex[columns=2, options=-s names.mst -C utf8 -L polish]
```

2. Zawartość końcowa/skorowidz.tex:

```
(...)

\printindex

(...)
```

3. names.mst:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\textbf\{"
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 ": "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 ": "
delim_r "\\nohyperpage{-}"
```

4. Example indexes with short part of text:

```
(... - from Rozdziały/planimetria.tex)

W dowolnym trójkącie dwusieczne\index{dwusieczna}, symetralne
\index{symetralna}, środkowe\index[names]{Srodkowa@Środkowa},
wysokości\index{wysokość} przecinają się w \myuline{jednym punkcie}.
(...)
```

[image: Indeks]

[image: Current look]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of linking to your full project. Try to assemble a short piece of code that can be compiled and results in the problem you are facing. It will be a lot easier to help you then.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Hmm... okey, thanks...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Is it better now?

Comment: Well, it is not really an MWE, but I guess, it is sufficient to grasp you ides. However, it seems that you relate to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276181/47927  . Note that `makeindex` and `xindy` are different programs to generate indices and they also use different options. It seems that you try to use options for `xindy` while using `makeindex`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Okey okey, so I should use `xindy` (texindy) instead of `makeindex`, yes?

Comment: I would suggest that you to it. See egreg's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137775/discussion-between-constantin-d-and-jasper-habicht).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal advice is to switch to `upmendex`. Create a file named `names.ist` with

```
icu_locale "pl"
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

The key point here is the line `icu_locale "pl"`. Just run

```
upmendex -s names <your file>.idx
```

Here is the example in previous answers, slightly modified. I don’t use `imakeidx`, so I don’t know how to deal with `upmendex`. This is why I run it by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=2]

\begin{document}

Some text

\index{a}
\index{ś}
\index{ć}
\index{s}
\index{al}
\index{c}
\index{sa}
\index{se}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

As to the line breaking with single letters, `babel` now provides this feature. See [one-letter word at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line/650146#650146) .

Comment: With combination of xindy on TeXstudio your idea works perfect... But in Overleaf there are problems with diacritic letters... Unfortunately... [link](https://imgur.com/fFnt7P2)

Answer (score 11):

You can't do it with `makeindex` because it cannot sort correctly other languages than English. Change to `xindy`.

Also `polski` is not compatible with LuaLaTeX, use `babel`.

Run with `-shell-escape` enabled, if you want automatic processing with `xindy`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=2, options=-C utf8 -L polish]

\begin{document}

Some text

\index{a}
\index{al}
\index{c}
\index{ć}
\index{s}
\index{sa}
\index{se}
\index{ś}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a big problem, because I use `\usepackage[nosingleletter]{impnattypo}`, which must be in LuaLaTeX to avoid single letters... Also, I have discovered, that some options in tikzpictures are damaged...

Example of errors (in planimetria.tex)

`Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. ...aw pic["$\delta$", angle radius = 8mm, draw] 
Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete. ...aw pic["$\delta$", angle radius = 8mm, draw]
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...aw pic["$\delta$", angle radius = 8mm, draw]`

Comment: @constantin_d You can compile with LuaLaTeX, why not?

Comment: Yes, but now I'm having problems with these bugs and similar .. can I upload the project again so you can see what I did wrong?

Comment: There's no way around it, you'll have to use a unicode-aware package like `xindy`. As to preventing line breaks after single letter words etc. check out the out `luavlna` package.

Comment: @egreg  We tried with Jasper your idea... Unfortunately, we still don't know, what is wrong in this case - your example works fine, but my isn't... Can You look on the current code?

Comment: @constantin_d Sorry, but it doesn't work like this. I'm not going to debug a huge project that takes ages even to fail and definitely not going to pay in order to get more compile time. Prepare a short example that shows the issues you have, but in a separate question, because those errors have nothing to do with the index.

Comment: @egreg Okey, sorry!

Comment: @egreg You have right of course about these errors, they had been solved recently, but not index... unfortunately :/ Sorry again...

Comment: @constantin_d You can turn shorthands off with the package option `shorthands=off`.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround, if using `xindy` is an option, could be that you sort words that start with ć or ś under C and S, using something like the following approach. You can use `xxx@xxx` as argument of the macro `\index` where everything in front of `@` is the sorting string, while the stuff in front of `@` is the string that will be printed:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{book}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\begin{filecontents}{names.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
\end{filecontents}

\makeindex[columns=2, options=-s names]

\begin{document}

Foo
\index{a}
\index{al}
\index{c}
\index{czz@ć}
\index{s}
\index{sa}
\index{se}
\index{szz@ś}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]