# Customizing index to make a list of words with the same beginning

Tags: xindy, customize, xindex, labelling

Do any of you how to make this part of my Index:

[image]

where "Principio de Arquimedes" means "Archimede's principle" to look something like this:

[image]

As you can see, I want that all the phrases that start with "Principio" (Principle) to be in some kind of a list.

If someone can tell me how, I'd appreciate that a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my answer is too late but anyway. In that place where you wrote `\index{Principio de Arquimedes}` and `\index{Principio de Pascal}` you should write `\index{Principio!de Arquimedes}` and `\index{Principio!de Pascal}`. This way you'll get a hierarchic index.

Comment: Nooo! It's not late! By the way, do you know which package creates `\index` command? I'd like to read the documentation to make a better index

Comment: @Peluche, sorry that I didn't answer 2 days ago. When I was doing alphabetical index for my document I had spent a lot of hours finding useful information, because I wanted to do miltilingual index. So, the best solution for me: ``\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}``. The command to make index: ``\makeindex[columns = 2, title = References, intoc, options = -s myindex.ist]``. To do the index you should create .ist file (for instanse, as it done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650880/300987). The file must be in the same folder with your main .tex file.

Comment: And the best way for me to do alphabetically sorted index is use ``upmendex``. I use Windows 10 and TeXstudio, so to include index to my main file I should do: 1. Compile main .tex file. 2. Run command line from the path where my .tex file is. 3. Paste there ``upmendex -s names <your file>.idx``, where "names" is your .ist file and "<your file>.idx" is an auxiliary file recieved from the first compilation of .tex file. 4. Compile main .tex file again. After that you'll get the index in your main file.